# How to optimize sms background service for battery and resources

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have an app in store, and a few users said that the app uses either too much battery, or it his hig mb in resources(10 or 20mb+). In my device its fine and on a few devices if seen it its fine.

I use an sms broadcast receiver to read all the incomming sms, and if i see any message i want to process i read it etc. So basically the service needs to run all the time so i dont lose any message that might come.

Is there a way to optimize this or to make the code lighter if its possible so that all users are ok with this? I know it might differ from device to device and from android version to version but giving it a shot would be good.

I didnt try anything yet as i dont have a clue what could be the problem or if there is actually one. And Ive searched a little and people say that the service shouldnt run all the time and should restart a few times or close it when not needed. But my sms receiver needs to run all the time.

Any ideas or anything i should check for?

My service by the way is startForeground, so it doesnt turn off from android.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a Service running constantly to receive incoming SMS. Simply register your BroadcastReceiver class in the manifest, and start an IntentService in `onReceive()` to handle whatever processing you need to do. The IntentService will stop itself when it is finished. Your app does not need an active component for a statically registered Receiver to be delivered the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast. The Receiver will be started by the system when delivering the Intent.

Comment: What if the phone restarts and i dont open the app. Will the sms broadcast be active then and read the incomming sms?

Comment: Yes. After installation, the user will need to run your app once to remove it from the _stopped_ state (on newer Android versions, at least), but beyond that, the Receiver will be registered to receive all pertinent broadcasts.

Comment: run the app once after each restart you mean right?

Comment: No. Once after installation.

Comment: Ok. Thats actually messed up a little for me since its already in store. So now if i want to remove my service and leave everything on the broadcast receiver, on my next update how do you suggest i should stop the service? Because obviously the service runs all the time and while the update is installed i need to call something to basically stop the service and set my broadcast receiver on a different class or place anw.

Comment: If it's the same package name, it will just be replaced. The system will kill the running Service when it installs the new version.

Comment: Ok thats all really helpful m8. Thank you very much. Ill try them on a test device and start making changes then. Cheers.