# Effective way to monitor for SMS's in the background, even after app execution ends

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I have developed an app wherein my requirement is that I have to monitor for SMS from a particular sender containing a particular text in the background. This I have done with relative success, using a combination of *asynctask and sentinel based while loop*. However, this won't work if I force kill my app after triggering the SMS monitoring, or if I leave the phone idle for hours after I trigger the process.

I realize that **background service** is probably the best way to go.

My requirements are:

1) The SMS monitoring has to be done in the background even if I kill my app after triggering the monitoring process.

2) If I want to deactivate this process at any time, I should be able to go back to my app, and do so on clicking some button.

3)The service should linger even if there is an intermediate power off of the phone.

How do I go about doing this in an effective manner? Detailed solutions with code/pseudocode would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You do not need a constantly running Service to monitor incoming SMS. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255653/how-to-optimize-sms-background-service-for-battery-and-resources/26256439#26256439) gives an outline for the solution. As far as code, there are hundreds of SMS Receiver examples already on the site.

Comment: What about my requirement 2)? I have to deactivate the service by simply opening my app and pressing a button. How would I be able to identify that service after I trigger it, possibly from a different instance of the same app?

Comment: The Intent Service is not going to be running constantly. It will finish itself when it's done logging the number, saving the message, or whatever it is you need it to do when a message is received. If you mean you want to toggle the monitoring, then there are a couple of options. You could set a Shared Preferences value in your Activity, read it in `onReceive()`, and act accordingly. Or you could enable/disable the Receiver using `PackageManager`.

Comment: Ok I will try this out, and get back to you if I have further queries